# Is obversion the same thing as inverse?

Tags: logic

Is obversion the same thing as inverse?
In reference to logic at least.

eh, I have been trying to find an answer online and it seems they are the same thing? A bit trivial, but just wanted to confirm.

Also, if they are the same thing, is 'obversion' used more often than 'inverse'? Is one or the other used more in certain contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same, at least when it comes to logic.

The definition of an inverse statement is if we have a conditional statement of the form $P \implies Q$, its inverse is $\neg P \implies \neg Q$. (In fact, inverses and converses are logically equivalent to each other since the inverse is the contrapositive of the converse.) For example, the inverse of "if I will get paid this week, then I will spend my money" is "if I won't spend my money, then I won't get paid this week."

But an obversion is changing the quality of a proposition and replacing the predicate with its complement. For instance, the obversion of "every person is trustworthy" is "no person is untrustworthy."

By the way, obversion statements are more philosophy-based, so I'm not too sure how much it relates to mathematics since I don't think it's standard for math-proof classes to teach it.

Comment: I visited the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obversion) to clarify what it means to "change the quality" of a proposition, but it's not made explicit there either.  Is it a categorical logic thing such that *every* and *no* are have different "qualities"? And *some*'s "quality" cannot be changed?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: A simple way to remember obversion in the Aristotelian term logic is to deem it like flipping a coin over from its reverse (tails) to its obverse (heads).

In this system, *quality* of a categorical proposition indicates whether a predicate of a subject is asserted (affirmative) or not (negative). *Quantity* of a categorical proposition indicates whether  it refers to all members of its subject class or a particular member.

By flipping over a predicate, taking the complementary extension of a predicate is intended. So,

1. All S is P

Keep the subject: S

Flip over the predicate: non-P

Flip over the quality: No S

∴ No S is non-P

2. Likewise: No S is P ∴ All S is non-P
3. Some S is P

Keep the subject: S

Flip over the predicate: non-P

Flip over the quality: Some S is not

∴ Some S is not non-P

4. Likewise: Some S is not P ∴ Some S is non-P

As mentioned in the previous answer, it is clearly divergent from the inverse of a conditional proposition.